# Streaming Cloudfront video to JWplayer embedded in colorbox

Tags: colorbox, jwplayer

I am trying to set up JWplayer to appear in a colorbox and play a movie streamed from CloudFront. It's not working properly, and I'm not sure if the problem is with JWplayer, Colorbox, or me :-)

Using JWplayer 5 with `<embed>` and `<object>` tags, it works fine. When I embed JWplayer 5 with `jwplayer.setup`, the width and height of the colorbox are transposed

Using JWplayer 6, the dimensions of the colorbox are transposed when streaming from
CloudFront, but they are correct when downloading from CloudFront.

There are also some other issues when playing the movies in Firefox and IE, but I am not 
concerned about them at the moment.

The code I am using to set up JWplayer 5 and Colorbox is as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox/example1/colorbox.css">
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/test/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<script src="/test/jwplayer5/jwplayer.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('a.cbox').colorbox({ inline:true, opacity:0.8 });
  });
</script>
```

This is the code I am using to embed JWplayer 5:

```
<a href="#example-1" class="cbox" title="Example 1">Play movie</a>

<div style="display: none;">
  <div id="example-1"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      jwplayer("example-1").setup({
      flashplayer: "/test/jwplayer5/player.swf",
      file: "dogs_600.mp4",
      streamer: "rtmp://s14flalja9b5hr.cloudfront.net/cfx/st",
      width: 480,
      height: 270,
      autostart: true
  });
  </script>
</div>
```

The code I am using to set up JWplayer 6 and Colorbox is as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox/example1/colorbox.css">
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/test/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<script src="/test/jwplayer6/jwplayer.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('a.cbox').colorbox({ inline:true, opacity:0.8 });
  });
</script>
```

The code I am using to emebed JWplayer 6 is as follows:

```
<a href="#example-1" class="cbox" title="Example 1: Streaming from CloudFront">Streaming from CloudFront</a><div style="display: none;">
  <div id="example-1"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("example-1").setup({
      file: "rtmp://s14flalja9b5hr.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/mp4:dogs_600.mp4",
      autostart: true,
      width: 480,
      height: 270
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

I have set up a couple of pages to demonstrate the problems:

http://www.frankcommunication.ie/test/jwplayer5-colorbox-example.htm
http://www.frankcommunication.ie/test/jwplayer6-colorbox-example.htm

The exact versions I am using are:

JWplayer 5.10.2295 (licensed)

JWplayer 6.2.3115 (unlicensed)

Colorbox v1.4.3

jQuery 1.9.1

Comment: I do think there might be a clash between ColorBox and our JS embedder, since the <embed> examples work fine. I have not personally used ColorBox, but I know that FancyBox works with our JS embedding method. If you are interested in a demo, please email me - http://www.longtailvideo.com/contact-us

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It's not evident from the contact page how to email you directly, but yes I would be interested in a demo of FancyBox.

Comment: Sure - support [at] longtailvideo [dot] com, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry it took so long to get round to this but I found the answer to my problem and wanted to add it here for the benefit of anyone who encounters the same problem in future...

I tried using FancyBox as suggested but it also had problems with dimensions so I went back to ColorBox and figured it out.

The fix was simple, all that's needed is to specify the dimensions as innerWidth and innerHeight parameters in your ColorBox setup, like this:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('a.cbox').colorbox({ 
        inline:true, 
        opacity:0.8,
        innerWidth: 480,
        innerHeight: 270
    });
  });
```

The JWplayer embed code is the same as before:

```
<a href="#example-1" class="cbox" title="Example 1">Play movie</a>

<div style="display: none;">
  <div id="example-1"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      jwplayer("example-1").setup({
          flashplayer: "/test/jwplayer5/player.swf",
          file: "dogs_600.mp4",
          streamer: "rtmp://s14flalja9b5hr.cloudfront.net/cfx/st",
          width: 480,
          height: 270,
          autostart: true
      });
  </script>
</div>
```